# how to synchronize jenkins' builds?

Tags: java, jenkins

my build consists of many stages. one of them is to perform database tests on a real database. i'd like to configure:

- one build that will test all important (whatever it means) branches
- second parametrized build: 'test my branch'

the problem is i have only 1 available database so the db test phase must be synchronized between builds. two processes can't use same database at same time or tests results will be wrong.

i didn't find any option to synchronize stages. is there any plugin or configuration option i missed?

Answer (score 3):

Look into the Jenkins Lockable Resources plugin.

Then define a "database" which as a lockable resource, and have both jobs require one database.  The job that is launched first will acquire the database and the secondary job will block.

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Lockable+Resources+Plugin

Answer (score 0):

First you may try to use Pipeline plugin which is creating workflow of builds which can be executed on one click:

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Pipeline+Plugin

Secondly if you can use junit test `@Category` which can group some tests and execute them for example usig maven profile